# Find the intersection between a linear equation and a quadratic equation, where the linear equation is x, not y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*What the title says essentially. Where one is x=0.6(y-4)^2+4 and another is x=15
The confusing part for me is that it is x=15, there is no y. There are a lot of help for y=?, but x=?*

**NEVERMIND, I figured out how to do it. Sorry guys ;)**

I am guessing I need to sub in 15 into the equation, then solve for y

Comment: NEVERMINE, I just figured how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to sub in 15 to the equation x=0.6(y-4)^2+4

That will give you the two y values in which the line intersects with the quadratic.